# Minimap Website Navigation

Tags: javascript, css, html, cookies, svg

I'm trying to make a website that will be structured as a "treasure-quest" game : the user will navigate between the pages as in these books where you are the hero and can jump between pages.

So this is just a matter of links, that will lead to a page or another.

But what I would like to do is to create a minimap that will show the user where he can go next, but will above all show him what paths he already took!

I was thinking of using cookies to keep informations of the visited pages, and then load a specific SVG showing the right paths according to these data.

Bu since I never used cookies before (and Javascript is pretty much unknown to me), I wanted to know if this can be the right solution or if there is a better option for me.

I attached a quick drawing of what I want to achieve to clarify this:
[image: Minimap Website drawing]

Thank you very much in advance, I would greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: [`a:visited`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited) might be a nice solution for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using local storage would be way to go. Whenever you want to save something that is reachable from the whole website and is saved even when you close the browser, you should use local storage.

A clean way would be keeping this information as a JSON array:

```
// Populate this array each time you visit a page
var pages = ['page1', 'page2']; 
// Store them as a stringified array
localStorage.setItem("pagesVisited", JSON.stringify(pages));
```

Then, when you need to reach that information, parse it:

```
var pagesObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("pagesVisited"));
```

This way, you will always have an object that remembers what is going on every page.

Comment: I completely forgot to answer you, but your response did the trick and I was able to do what I wanted using local storage! I will mark your answer as accepted, thank you.

Comment: Very glad to hear that it helped! I thought my answer wasn't clear enough and it assumed you already knew certain stuff. I'm excited about your project!